# exec() function in python not executing in django

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-views

Hope you all are fine.
I want to use the exec() function in django to execute my strings picked from the database.
The code I wrote is working in just python script but not working in Django views. Below is my code in python script which I'm running in notebook.

```
ticker = 'AAPL'
title = 'f"hey {ticker} is a really doing good."'
exec('title = ' + title)
print(title)
```

But same code in Django views is not executing. Below is the code in views.py.

```
ticker = 'AAPL'
title = queryset.title #The title here is The {ticker} is not doing good.
exec('title = ' + title)
```

It is not giving the write anwser, just returning the first title as shown below.

> The {ticker} is not doing good. Thats is the {ticker} body.

If anyone have any solution, kindly help me to figure it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer.
If you want to execute one variable, then use the upper code which is:

```
ticker = 'AAPL'
title = queryset.title.format(ticker=ticker)
```

If you want to execute whole dictionary with alot of values. Then ** is a good option. For example

```
dictionary = {'ticker': 'Example', 'website': 'example.com'}
queryset.title.format(**dictionary)
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [**`str.format(…)`** [Python-doc]](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) to format strings:

```
ticker = 'AAPL'
title = queryset.title.format(ticker=ticker)
```

do *not* use `exec` or `eval`: it can result in unwanted side-effects and is thus not secure.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answering. Just one more question. This is not one value. I have a dictionary, and in the string, I have written like this, {dictionary.name}. I want to execute all of them.